# How to replace delimited column value in SQL update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Values in Column are in format `Name_city_age_ID` (underscore separated).
Age was always blank. Other values may or not be blank. So values in column are like:

```
John_London__1223,
Mary_Paris__,
Dave____,
Smith____1012,
___2334
```

Now I have the age as 22 for all rows & I want to replace all values in the column, So the new columns should be:

```
John_London_22_1223,
Mary_Paris_22_,
Dave__22_,
Smith__22_1012,
__22_2334,
```

How to write the update query for this?

Comment: What type of database is this? Are your rows comma-delimited?

Comment: What do you have four underscores in some rows?

Comment: **DON'T USE DELIMITED COLUMNS!**

Answer (score 1):

Using `STUFF`, but you should really normalize your data. This looks for the second instance of `_` and adds `22`.

```
declare @table table(col varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('John_London__1223'),
('Mary_Paris__'),
('Dave____'),
('Smith____1012'),
('___2334')

select * from @table

--update the column 

update @table
set col = stuff(col,charindex('_',col) + charindex('_',right(col,len(col) - charindex('_',col))) + 1,0,'22')


--see the results

select * from @table
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `CHARINDEX` function twice should do it. The following is the SELECT query for reviewing results, convert to UPDATE:

```
SELECT
  str,
  STUFF(str, CHARINDEX('_', str, CHARINDEX('_', str) + 1) + 1, 0, '22') AS newstr
FROM testdata
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b39a/5)